# How do I fix an application that is throwing Exception (Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException Stack) when installed in a client machine

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that is working fine during testing and application development, but when I build and install the application in an external system, it works, then throws an exception when creating a new window. Here is the form's constructor code and Load event

```
 public VoucherForm(int transactionId)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            _voucherTransactionId = transactionId;
            _settingService = new SettingService();
            _transactionService = new TransactionService();
            _voucherController = new PaymentVoucherController();

        }

 private void VoucherForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _panelWidth = voucherPanel.Width;

            _paymentVoucher = PaymentVoucherController.GetPaymentVoucher;

            if (_paymentVoucher == null)
            {
                var voucher = _voucherController
                    .ReloadVoucher(_voucherTransactionId);

                if (voucher == null)
                {
                    const string msg = "Cannot display voucher.";
                MessageBox.Show(msg, Resources.ActionNotSuccessful,
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                this.Close();
                }
                _paymentVoucher = voucher;
            }

            LoadVoucherTitles();

            //Load payment voucher
            LoadPaymentVoucher();
        }
```

and here is the stack trace when it throws the exception and shuts down.

```
The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
Stack:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32)
   at PPSMB.UI.Common.ExceptionHandler.Handle(System.Exception)
   at PPSMB.UI.MainForm.Application_ThreadException(System.Object, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.OnThreadException(System.Exception)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(System.Exception)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadException(System.Exception)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
   at PPSMB.UI.Program.Main()
```

Please any help as to the cause of these exception will be greatly appreciated as am under the constraint of time.

**EDIT**

Here is the handle method

```
public static void Handle(Exception exception)
        {
            var documentsPath = Environment
                .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

            var exceptionString = exception.ToString();

            documentsPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Ppsmb");

            if (!Directory.Exists(documentsPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsPath);
            }
            var fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            var erorPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "{0}_error.txt", fileName);

            erorPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, erorPath);

            FileStream stream = null;
            if (!File.Exists(erorPath))
            {
                stream = File.Create(erorPath);
            }
            else
            {
                stream = File.OpenWrite(documentsPath);
            }

            using (var strStream = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                strStream.WriteLine(exceptionString);
                strStream.Flush();
                strStream.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
```

This method is called by

```
 private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            const string exceptionMsg = "An error has occured!, " +
                                        "please close the application and " +
                                        "restart it again.";

            Exception exception = args.Exception;
            ExceptionHandler.Handle(exception);

            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(exceptionMsg, "ERROR!",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code in that example that deals with streams, which is where the exception is thrown in the stacktrace. Can you show the relevant code? For instance, show the method `Application_ThreadException`.

Comment: What happens in this method: PPSMB.UI.Common.ExceptionHandler.Handle() ? This is the last method that is called before your stream, so I suspect this is being called and is trying to write the error it has received to a log file that doesn't exist. Without seeing the code I'm just speculating though.

Comment: Okay let me edit the post and show the code.

Comment: Hi  @Pheonyx, have edited the question and updated the code.

Comment: Here's what I think's happening: An exception is occurring in `VoucherForm_Load()`, which is being handled via code attached to the `Application.ThreadException` event. This code is attempting to do some logging, and THAT is causing a different exception, which is hiding the first exception.

Comment: Thanks, how do I debug the handle exception method, to know whats causing the exception, since this exception does not occur in my development machine

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about these two lines of code:

```
var erorPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "{0}_error.txt", fileName);
erorPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, erorPath);
```

I think this is causing your error, which as Matthew pointed out, is hiding another error.

Try changing those two lines to this single:

```
var erorPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, string.Format("{0}_error.txt", filename));
```

Comment: I have seen where the first exception is occurring. It is when I try to create a text file to log the error. Still testing the new code that I have written though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create the documents folder if it does not exist. Run your app as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

please check your folder/directory permission.
If not give all the necessary read,write etc rights for all the users.